# Access to a record just inserted

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm working with the sqlite3 library under python 3.5.

I have defined two tables, related through a foreign key, with the following structures:

Table 1 structure:

```
'Table1_ID' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE
'Name' TEXT
```

Table 2 structure:

```
'Table2_ID' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE
other fields
'NameID' INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`NameID`) REFERENCES table_1 ( Table1_ID )
```

Then I want to add a record on Table1, and subsequently add a record on Table2 that references the record just inserted in Table1. The steps would be:

1. Add record to Table1 using an INSERT query - the database engine will assign a unique Table1_ID integer automatically
2. Somehow read that Table1_ID value, say Table1_ID=821
3. Add a record to Table2 using an INSERT query, where I specify that NameID=821

Now, my question is about the most efficient way of implementing step 2.
An obvious option is to execute a "SELECT" query to get the cursor over the just inserted record, and then read its Table1_ID value.

But I am wondering whether there is an alternative way of knowing Table1_ID juts after the INSERT record without having to execute a second query.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DeepSpace. That solution has the risk that another transaction may have altered the value of lastrowid. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: Forget my previous comment, I just realised that different cursors would avoid this problem. My question is certainly a duplicate of the one you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for coming to the conclusion that they are! I have no experience in sqllite3 and couldn't decide on my own. You can either delete your question or let it hang around as a flagpost for other users facing a similar problem. I will edit your question and remove the *UPDATE* section now :-)